# How to deal with varying sample frequency in a time series

Tags: time-series

I have  a time series of a sensor and I want to calculate the mean, standard deviation and other statistics. But the data has varying sample frequency. Sometimes I have a point every 60 secs , other times 120, other times 40 and so on.
I thought about interpolanting the points in a 60 sec fixed interval, and because sometimes the interval could be like 1 day,I will invalidated the interpolated points that are very far from real points. There is a better idea ?